# How to remove sticking to the edges of the platform in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to know how I can get rid of wall sticking in my movement code. I believe the reason is that I implemented it via AddForce, however, I don't know how to fix it. I will be grateful for any help.

Attaching the code:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Movement")]
public float moveSpeed;
public float walkSpeed;
public float sprintSpeed;

public float groundDrag;

public float jumpForce;
public float jumpCooldown;
public float airMultiplier;

[Header("Keybinds")]
public KeyCode sprintKey = KeyCode.LeftShift;

[Header("Ground Check")]
public float playerHeight;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
bool grounded;

public Transform orientation;

float horizontalInput;
float verticalInput;

Vector3 moveDirection;

Rigidbody rb;
public MovementState state;

public enum MovementState
{
    walking,
    sprinting,
    air
}

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.freezeRotation = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    grounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.2f, whatIsGround);

    MyInput();
    SpeedControl();
    StateHandler();

    if (grounded)
        rb.drag = groundDrag;
    else
        rb.drag = 0;

}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    MovePlayer();
}

private void MyInput()
{
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
}

private void StateHandler()
{
    if(grounded && Input.GetKey(sprintKey))
    {
        state = MovementState.sprinting;
        moveSpeed = sprintSpeed;
    }
    else if (grounded)
    {
        state = MovementState.walking;
        moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
    }
    else
    {
        state = MovementState.air;
    }
}

void MovePlayer()
{
    moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;
    if(grounded)
        rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
    else if(!grounded)
        rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f * airMultiplier, ForceMode.Force);
}

private void SpeedControl()
{
    Vector3 flatVel = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);

    if(flatVel.magnitude > moveSpeed)
    {
        Vector3 limitedVel = flatVel.normalized * moveSpeed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(limitedVel.x, rb.velocity.y, limitedVel.z);
    }
}

}
```

I left the sprint in the code, because, perhaps, he also looked at something

Addition:

The error occurs when I walk facing the wall (W). If I change direction, then the walk goes fine. I would like to change it to something like sliding like in most games

Ad:

I mean -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt5Lx.png)

Comment: might want to look into [Physics Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html)

Comment: @derHugo , Thanks, that's an interesting thing, but at a right angle, the character still hangs in the air stuck to the wall, even when using the value 0 for all parameters of the Physic Material

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to set the Friction Combine value to Minimum when using the Physic Material